# Linux: I can not understand a `m4` command

Tags: m4

My work is converting Linux command into CMake `execute_process(COMMAND ...)`, and there are some differences between them, so i need to understand each Linux command. But this m4 command really  beat me. The m4 command as below:

```
m4 -Isource/analyzer/ -P < source/analyzer/aParser.m4y > source/analyzer/aParser.by
```

What does this command mean?

I have read m4 document before, and it said the format of the `m4` command is:   `m4 [option…] [file…]`, so i think  in command:

```
m4 -Isource/analyzer/ -P < source/analyzer/aParser.m4y > source/analyzer/aParser.by
```

the `-Isource/analyzer/ -P` is `[option...]` of `m4`, and this `m4` commad use`<`to read the file `source/analyzer/aParser.m4y` as m4 `[file...]`, did i understand right?

Comment: This quesion does not show any effort or research. Downvoting.

Comment: [This page](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/m4/manual/m4-1.4.17/html_node/Command-line-files.html#Command-line-files) explicitely says, that without specifying input file names `m4` reads *standard input stream*. Redirectrion `<` provides content for that stream.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, thanks a lot, i just want to confirm it, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[m4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4_%28computer_language%29) is a macro processor. Read its [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/m4.html) (for GNU m4). It is a quite complex thing, so I won't try to abstract it in a few sentences.
The [`-P` option](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/m4/manual/m4-1.4.17/html_node/Operation-modes.html#Operation-modes) is prefixing builtins with `m4_` so `define` becomes `m4_define` etc...

The `<` (and `>`) is not an option to m4, it is a general shell [redirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29).

Of course, you also need to study the documentation of [cmake](https://cmake.org/) (which I personally don't like much, since [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make) 4 is powerful enough *without* `cmake`)

You probably should spend weeks in reading documentations, including [Advanced Bash Scripting guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) & [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) (and the other documentations I pointed here).

Comment: I have read this document before, and it said the format of the m4 command is: `m4 [option…] [file…]`, i am wondering weather the `< source/analyzer/aParser.m4y` in the `middel `means `aParser.m4y` use `<` as the `[file…]`, and then wirte the content of  `aParser.m4y` into `aParser.by` at the `last`?

Comment: I don't understand what you actually have understood. I strongly suggest to spend *weeks* in reading documentation.

Comment: I mean in command:`m4 -Isource/analyzer/ -P < source/analyzer/aParser.m4y > source/analyzer/aParser.by`,  `-Isource/analyzer/ -P` is `[option...]` of m4, and this m4 commad use`<`to read the file `source/analyzer/aParser.m4y` as `m4` `[file...]`

Comment: Please read documentation. I don't want and don't have time to explain you all the basics. I gave you many links.

Comment: My project is very urgent, and this command is the last i have to process, i would surely like to reading documentation detailedly when i am free. Thanks for your help. :-)

Comment: Then, ask your boss to have some more weeks. Or to subcontract your own work.